# Spring 3 - InternalResourceViewResolver is not displaying my jsp page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to make a sample Spring 3 Web Hello World sample but InternalResourceViewResolver is not displaying my jsp page?

**web.xml**

```
[CODE]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>testbox</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/forms/*</url-pattern>


    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>[/CODE]
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
[CODE]<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>[/CODE]
```

can someone please tell me whats up or how to debug it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please post your controller code and is your jsp located in /WEB-INF/views?

Make sure that your jsp filename is the same to that of your return string in your controller method.

If you have several static jsp and defining them using  `<mvc:view-controller>` is unpretty, you can define a controller similar to this

```
 @Controller 
 public class MyController {

   @RequestMapping("/view/{name}")  
     public String myView(@PathVariable("name") String  name) {
      return name;   
   }

}
```

Your jsp is now accessible via url "/view/"

Comment: my jsp page is in web-inf/views but i dont have a controller! do i need one just to make a passtho?

Comment: without a controller, you can specifically define a static view specifying something like this on your dispatcher context config: <mvc:view-controller path="/myjsp"/>

Comment: i added this <mvc:view-controller path="/*"/> is this right??  i have a number of jsps to file thats why or do you know a better way?

Comment: mvc:view-controller lets you define static views without requiring an actual controller class. You will have to define each jsp using that. If you have several jsp and you're planning to add more, i recommend you implement a controller for that already.